# Docker and kubernetes capabilities

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, netlink, capability

i have a question and a problem about capabilities.

Why my program work when i run docker `run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN`... ? ( i don't have RTNETLINK problems and TC Network problems with ETH0)

And it's doesn't work if i run my program with file .yml which is:

```
  containers:
  - name: snake
    image: docker.io/kelysa/snake:lastest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      capabilities:
        add: ["NET_ADMIN","NET_RAW"]
```

i have problems like `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

```
tc isn't available for interface eth0"
"NETWORK_BANDWIDTH requires traffic control (tc). 
CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_NET_ADMIN+ capability is also required, with modinfo sch_netem.
```

What is the difference between run docker with --cap-add and run a pod with the same capabilities ?

Comment: Could you provide your interfaces? Are you trying to run it on clean docker or on minikube? Also could you provide YAML? I would like to reproduce it locally,

Comment: Sorry i can't provide you this project. but i'm trying to run it with minikube, it's doesn't work. When i used docker with --cap-add=NET_ADMIN it's work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between --cap-add=NET\_ADMIN and add capabilities in .yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377469/difference-between-cap-add-net-admin-and-add-capabilities-in-yml)